# How to create an enemy that you defeat by tapping as it falls from the top of the screen?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making a game using android eclipse(java) where enemies fall from the top of the screen to the bottom. I have succeeded in making them fall (a little too fast but good enough for now) but I have not been able to make them respond correctly to tapping. At first, all enemies were defeated wherever the touch occurred but now there is no response at all. My question is how do i correctly read the player input. Thanks to anyone who reads this. This is my first post so I apologize if the question was posed incorrectly.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

    switch (e.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

    // Player has touched the screen
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        paused = false;
        // Has the player tapped an alien
        for (int i = 0; i < enemyNumb; i++) {
            if (aliens[i].getVisibility() & aliens[i].getX() == e.getX() & aliens[i].getY() == e.getY()) {  // Enemy defeated code goes here
```

Comment: You are trying to respond to a click on a single pixel? You likely need to implement a box that you can more accurately detect a click within

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it to work by using a box to detect a click within. This is what i used before but the aliens were put into the same box so they all disappeared and it made me believe that it was wrong. Thank you cricket_007  for the suggestion.

```
    if ( aliens[i].getRect().contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
```